# Make Emacs indent code in every possible situation

Tags: emacs, indentation

I can't seem to get Emacs to just use Tab for indentation. I set c-tab-always-indent and tab-always-indent to true, but still I have to use C-q Tab to indent a line of code.

What do I need to do to just make Tab indent in every possible situation?

Comment: Are you in c-mode when you get the tab inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Emacs, "indent" means having Emacs automatically determine the indentation for the current line. What <kbd>C-q TAB</kbd> does is simply insert a tab character. If that’s what you want, you could bind <kbd>TAB</kbd> to `self-insert-command`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'self-insert-command)
(define-key c-mode-base-map (kbd "TAB") 'self-insert-command)
```